# Need to set up data values in $this->request->data object for testing purpose

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I am using **CakePHP 2.X** and need to use the `$this->request->data->object (or a Mock)` to test a Controller method. I have a condition in the controller that verify if `$this->request->data is empty (if (empty($this->request->data)) {EXECUTE SOMETHING})` and I need to add data in this object on the testing side, to not enter in the if statement.

I've been looking on the web already and didn't find anything that suits me. Here's the Controller Code :

```
function default($user = null) {
$subsite = $this->Session->read('subsite');
        if ($subsite == "www" || $subsite == "xxx") {
            $this->redirect("/application/addtool");
            return "ok1";
        }
        if (empty($this->request->data)) {
            $this->render();
        } else {
            $this->request->data['Project']['actif'] = true;
            $user_id = $this->Session->read('user_id');
            $this->request->data['Project']['user_id'] = $user_id;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass data in a test, you supply the second argument of `testAction` with an array of data in the `data` key:

```php
$this->testAction('/default', [
    'data' => [
        'some' => 'data',
    ],
    'method' => 'post',
]);
```

This will construct a test request with `['some' => 'data']` in the request data.

For more information: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do these data would be the data available in the $this->request->data object ?

Comment: Yes, `testAction` will build a request containing that as the data, which will end up in `$this->request->data`